# How to execute only "mvn test" without executing dependent goals "clean' and "compile"?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am executing Cucumber test suite from multiple command prompts, but "mvn test" command executed from each cmd, calls 'clean' and 'compile' goals internally, which refresh the classes in JVM and that throws  'NoClassDefFoundError' exception for any random classes while the scripts are executing.
I want to execute multiple feature files in parallel to reduce execution time.
Since my framework is integration of Selenium/Cucumber/TestNG/Maven & OATS and executes as complex workflow, I can not use 'fork' feature to execute in multiple threads. Just looking for some way to execute "mvn test" goal independently.

Also tried with "mvn surefire:test" but something is wrong in my pom.xml  node, so that is not working. Please suggest the template for pom.xml to execute using "mvn surefire:test"

Comment: An `mvn test` will not call `clean` but it will run the life cycle which includes `compile`...I don't understand your relation to scripts? without full pom file and full log of the error it's hard...to guess what's wrong... I don't understand what you've mentioned that something is wrong in your pom ?

Comment: Requirement to execute end to end scenarios (contains 5-7 test cases) by automation suite. Scripts are coded in Selenium/Cucumber & OATS tools. Scripts have to run in specific order. So, created a workflow of test cases and executing it 1 by 1 using a masterscript, which triggers cmd for Selenium execution (mvn test) & OATS (runScript.bat) based on testcase. To speed up exec, I am triggering this masterscript from 4 diff batch files, but it cause NoClassDef. error bcoz while one script is executing, another cmd triggers compile. So, I want maven to run 'only test' instead of re-compiling

Comment: Selenium tests are by definition integration tests and should run with maven-failsafe-plugin. What I don't understand why you run a script `runScript.bat`? Why not implemented in your java test code?. Best would be to make an example project and put it on github or alike and them we might have a chance to understand what you are trying to accomplish and maybe we are able to help.

Comment: Can't put code on github,.....but application is divided into PEGA and Oracle forms. So, PEGA part of automated using Cucumber/Selenium and Oracle forms are automated using OATS. runScript.bat is part of OATS and executed using that. In simple words, I am looking for a way to execute "mvn test" goal only without recompiling the code.

Comment: What you could try is to call `mvn surefire:test` and call the plugin goal but this is hack I strongly discourage it to do so...cause the life cycle has a good intention....

Comment: I tried "mvn surefire:test" command, but it could not trigger any test case. I see console message as "No Test to Run". pom.xml works well with "mvn test" command, but not with "mvn surefire:test". Is there anything specific change I need to do in pom.xml to make it run for "mvn surefire:test" command?